# Plotting multi-indexed data with subplots only at one level

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

**Edit with example data in code format:**

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Station':  ['station 1', 'station 1', 'station 1', 'station 1','station 2', 'station 2','station 2', 'station 2', 'station 2', 'station 2'],
        'month': ['March', 'Arpil', 'March', 'Arpil','March', 'Arpil','March', 'Arpil', 'March', 'Arpil'],
         'x1': ['22', '42', '11', '56','28', '33','87', '34', '11', '25'],
      'x2': ['52', '47', '31', '52','38', '35','47', '54', '10', '45']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.groupby(['Station','month']).mean()

df.transpose().plot(subplots=True, kind='bar')
```

**I am unable to get separate subplots for station, a cluster of bars in each subplot for category (e.g, x1), and each cluster representing one month (see Excel graph for representative subplot).**

I have a dataframe (that I've converted to excel for the purpose of asking this question) that is organized in the following way:

[image: DF format]

I'm looking to generate subplots at the station level that have clustered bars for every quality (X2, X2..etc.) month to month. I don't think I'm doing a great job of describing that, so I created an example subplot in Excel.

[image: Example of one subplot.]

I would ideally have a subplot that looked like that for every station. I have figured out how to generate a sub plot for each station, but I can't figure out how to integrate the time element (and the clustered bars).

Comment: It looks like Matplotlib doesn't have a specialized plotting functionality for *clustered* bar charts. The `plt.bar()` function does have a `width` argument though, which can be used to obtain your desired result, through some fiddling. See [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-grouped-bar-plot-in-matplotlib/).

Comment: Can you share your efforts that you have put in code

Comment: Without worrying about the date field, I've been using the following to quickly generate subplots on these data:  
'df.plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, color='y', stacked=True, figsize=(40,200),\ sharex=False, layout=(11,2), legend=False, sharey=True, fontsize=20) '
 


When I use the date field I end up with a subplot not only for each station, but for each station-month. I want to condense it back down to the station level and have the dates represented within each station subplot.

Comment: This is much easier for us to pick up and alter if you post copy-pastable data and code; it can be just two qualities for three months, so the data doesn't take up much room (and make fake data if it's private!). [Details of minimal examples here.](  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry! I have added code for a DF that's a smaller version of what I'm working with (but is otherwise representative).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think pandas convenience wrapper for matplotlib natively supports grouped bar charts in subplots. The [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) say `subplots (bool, default False): Make separate subplots for each column.` Even 2x2 multiindex columns are interpreted as 4 columns and distributed into 4 subplots.
But this looks like a perfect case for employing [**seaborn**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot) that was written to make such data visualizations easier:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = {'Station':  ['station 1', 'station 1', 'station 1', 'station 1','station 2', 'station 2','station 2', 'station 2', 'station 2', 'station 2'],
        'month': ['March', 'Arpil', 'March', 'Arpil','March', 'Arpil','March', 'Arpil', 'March', 'Arpil'],
         'x1': ['22', '42', '11', '56','28', '33','87', '34', '11', '25'],
      'x2': ['52', '47', '31', '52','38', '35','47', '54', '10', '45']
        }
#data import and conversion to numeric 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore")

#transformation of the df into the long form
df_plot = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["Station", "month"], value_vars=["x1", "x2"], var_name="cat")
#generating the category plot
sns.catplot(x="cat", y="value", hue="month", col="Station", data=df_plot, kind="bar", ci=None)

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

The [**pandas**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#bar-plots)/[**matplotlib**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html?highlight=subplots) equivalent is slightly more verbose:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = {'Station':  ['station 1', 'station 1', 'station 1', 'station 1','station 2', 'station 2','station 2', 'station 2', 'station 2', 'station 2'],
        'month': ['March', 'Arpil', 'March', 'Arpil','March', 'Arpil','March', 'Arpil', 'March', 'Arpil'],
         'x1': ['22', '42', '11', '56','28', '33','87', '34', '11', '25'],
      'x2': ['52', '47', '31', '52','38', '35','47', '54', '10', '45']
        }
#data import and conversion to numeric 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore")

#data aggregation
df_plot = df.groupby(['Station','month'], sort=False).mean().unstack()

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(df_plot), sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(10, 5))
for station, curr_ax in zip(df_plot.index, axes):
    df_plot.loc[station].unstack().plot(kind="bar", ax=curr_ax, title=station)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate the help.